# Variable within liquid if statement when calling shopify settings

Tags: shopify, liquid

I thought this would be simple to solve but I am trying to put a variable within a liquid statement.

I have my variable `{{ loop_index }}` and I want it to be within this statement :

```
{% if settings.dropdown-[loop_index]-select  %}
```

I tried putting [...] round it but that didn't work. Basically it should say settings.dropdown-1-select, settings.dropdown-2-select.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a string containing the variable name, then use the [square bracket notation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/basics/handle#attributes-handle) to access the setting with that name. For example:

```
{% capture var %}dropdown-{{ loop_index }}-select{% endcapture %}
{% if settings[var] %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a while until I found this!