# Is there a way for concatenate two strings and then process the result inside the Output tags not as a string?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Here's what I am trying to accomplish:

```
  <ul class="site-nav__dropdown">
    {% for childlink in linklists[child_list_handle].links %}
this - {% assign color_from_settings = 'settings.collection_color_' | append: forloop.index %}
used here -  <li{% if childlink.active %} class="site-nav--active" {% else %} style="background-color: {{ color_from_settings }}" {% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="site-nav__link">{{ childlink.title | escape }}</a>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

When this gets rendered I get:

```
background-color: settings.collection_color_1;
```

instead of the actual color fetched from settings_data.json which looks like this:

```
{
  "current": "Default",
  "presets": {
    "Default": {
      ...
      "collection_color_1": "#9997c0",
      "collection_color_2": "#8997b1",
      "collection_color_3": "#7997a2",
      "collection_color_4": "#699793",
      "collection_color_5": "#599784",
      "collection_color_6": "#499775",
      "collection_color_7": "#399766",
      "collection_color_8": "#299757",
      "collection_color_9": "#199748",
      "collection_color_10": "#099739"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this programmatically, or do I really have to use <% case forloop.index %> ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28774494/1367622).

Try this:

```
{% assign color_from_settings = 'collection_color_' | append:forloop.index %}
...
{{ settings[color_from_settings] }}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Weirdly I got ":" as an output instead of the color value. The exact code I used is this:
`<li{% if childlink.active %} class="site-nav--active" {% else %} style="background-color: {{ settings[color_from_settings] }}"{% endif %}>`
I also tried `{% settings[color_from_settings] %}` but this didn't even upload (using shopify ruby gem). Gave me a "422 Unprocessable Entity" error.

Comment: It worked for me-
{% for i in (1..2) %}
  {% assign color_from_settings = 'collection_color_' | append:forloop.index %}
  <li class="site-nav--active" style="background-color: {{ settings[color_from_settings] }}">1 </li>
  {% endfor %}

Comment: Ah... sorry, it does work. I forgot to change 'settings.collection_color_' to 'collection_color_'. Silly me...